# RGraph reload the previous graph when i reload the page and i click the body of the page

Tags: rgraph

i use that for clear the graphs:

```
for (var i=0; i< document.getElementsByTagName('canvas').length; i++) {
RGraph.Clear(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[i]);
}
```

when i reload the page the previous appear and the new graph is placed over the last one, and the new label is placed above the last one

i use donut and pie charts

thankss!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to clear the ObjectRegistry, which keeps track of objects. You can do that with:

```
RGraph.ObjectRegistry.Clear();
```

Or you can clear objects related to a specific canvas tag with:

```
RGraph.ObjectRegistry.Clear(myCanvas);
```

Or you can remove a specific object with:

```
RGraph.ObjectRegistry.Remove(myObject);
```

You can read more about the ObjectRegistry on the API docs page:

https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/api.html#objectregistry

Comment: That almost solves the history issue. Combine with Happy's answer to also clear the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use RGraph.Clear(document.getElementById("The Id of your element"));

Comment: That correctly clears the canvas but barfs draw history when the page (radiobutton in my case) is clicked.